# facebook Share App ID Missing

Tags: facebook, share

Im trying to place fb `like` and `share` buttons on my site, following [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters) instructions.

Debugging the code on [facebook debug page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing) I'm getting the following warning:

```
Share App ID Missing
The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
```

I don't have any app on facebook and I don't want to have any.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this into your HTML

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="966242223397117" />
```

That is default app id.

Comment: You can find more clear ans at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066102/facebook-debugger-why-complaining-about-app-id-missing/38692177#38692177